# How to convert string data:audio/ogg;base64 to file wav in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, audio

I have a string like this:

```
"data:audio/ogg;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAAAbYwAAAAAAABodbEQBE09wdXNIZWFkAQE4AYA+AAAAAABPZ2dTAAAAAAAAAAAAABtjAAABAAAASJutcAE4T3B1c1RhZ3...h3KrMzThXiwEUg="
```

This string I get by an AJAX post using the following code:

```
var reader = new window.FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
reader.onloadend = function() {
    var base64Data = reader.result;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/ConvertToWav",
        type: "POST",
        data: { base64Data : base64Data }
    });
};
```

I want to convert this string to file wav via C# in action ConvertToWav.

Comment: Decode the base 64 data and convert it to wav using some Ogg decoder. What are you asking?

Comment: Why are you sending a blob as a string? Just upload the blob... http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-blob

Comment: @spender: I have tried upload blob as file and save to wav file, but the file can not open and play.

Comment: @Luaan: Yes, I just want to convert this string to file wav

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Alvas.Audio](http://alvas.net/)

```
byte[] byteAry= Convert.FromBase64String(myBase64String);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteAry);
WaveReader wr = new WaveReader(stream);
IntPtr format = wr.ReadFormat();
byte[] data = wr.ReadData();
WaveWriter ww = new WaveWriter(File.Create(fileName + ".wav"),AudioCompressionManager.FormatBytes(format));
ww.WriteData(data);
ww.Close();
```